# How to load $.ajax (jquery) response to iframe every 20 seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

How i can load this jquery get response to middle iframe in my page? The php script loads some data from mysql db? in this case i am not passing any data to php so do i need to make get or post request ? my code display the jquery response in alert but doesn't load it into iframe!

```
    setInterval(function() {

      $.ajax(
    {
        type: 'GET',
        url: './getDataFromMySQLdb.php',
        //data: $("#myform").serialize(),

         data: {
         title: 'test',
          // wrapper: 'testing'
         },
                success: function (good)
                {
                  //handle success

                      alert(good);
                    $("#middle").attr('src',+good); //change url
                },
                failure: function (bad)
                {
                   //handle any errors

                  alert(bad)

                }


    });
    }, 20000);

<iframe name="top" src="blank.php" id="top"  scrolling="no" noresize frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" width="100%" height="79"></iframe>
<iframe NAME="middle" src="blank.php" id="middle" noresize frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" width="100%" height="238" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
<iframe NAME="foot" src="blank.php" id="foot"  scrolling="no"  noresize frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" width="100%" height="200"></iframe>
```

Comment: `+good` should just be `good`

Comment: Thanks for reply . I tried good too before i post it doesn't work. I redirect me to a wrong page!

Comment: What page does it redirect you to?

Comment: it takes me to some advertizement page from my web hoster!

Comment: That sounds like a 404, invalid domain, or the like.  Maybe you should use an absolute path in the URL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply reload directly the iframe every 20 seconds, no need for $.ajax() :

```
setInterval(function(){
   $("#middle").attr('src', './getDataFromMySQLdb.php');
}, 20000);
```

However, I think that it will be better for you to not use an iframe at all.
Instead, just use a div with the same id='middle', and load the result directly into it:

```
setInterval(function(){
   $("#middle").load('./getDataFromMySQLdb.php');
}, 20000);
```

Comment: Does your first code make the iframe reload every 20 seconds or it just updates data? I am kind of intrested in not being able to see reload action in browser! Is that possible?

Comment: The first piece of code, that sets the src of the iframe, will force it to reload.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be some errors in your AJAX script, but you would be right in using a GET request. Please see below for something that might be what you're looking for. Also I can't see why you are loading this information into an iFrame? I would load it into a div instead. I might be completely misunderstood in what you're trying to achieve so the below might be of no help.

```
setInterval(function() {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '../getDataFromMySQLdb.php',
        data: '',
        success: function (data){
           $("#middleDiv").html(data);
        },
        failure: function (){
           alert('Error message');
        }
    });
}, 20000);
```

`<div id="middleDiv"></div>`

Comment: thanks for reply . I already know how to load it into div. But my goal is to be able to click in one item in my ajax response(its a clickable text just like hyper link) in middle iframe and it take that value and insert it to another table in mysql and show confirmation in footer frame that record has been inserted .All this without taking user to next page ! That is the reason i am trying to load it in middle iframe. Hope you guys help me with it .Thanks